# How to implement HLS video service with Vue3.js single page application

Tags: node.js, vue.js, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I'm creating video streaming platform with Vue.js. However, I encountered the question that I couldn't solve. That is when we use SPA like Vue.js, javascript are running on browser, so we have to receive segment files from server side API. If I use MPA, all I have to do is to specify the location of .m3u8 file.
I am using express for Node.js.

My question is how to create API that sends .m3u8 file and segment .ts files to client side Vue.js. Now, all .m3u8 and .ts segment files are all in server side, so I would like to know how to access or receive data from serverside API using SPA and node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I am front-end developer, and I can describe only the second part, how to process m3u8 in vue3.

1. on front-end part, you should reciev link on video as a responce from api [for deep answer, you need wait for a back-end develoepr]
2. then if you gona use video in  m3u8 format, you need to install
   npm i vue-hls-video-player

and just use a component, examples:

```
  <VideoPlayer
    type="default"
    @pause="processPause"
    previewImageLink="poster.webp"
    link="videoLink.m3u8"
    :progress="30"
    :isMuted="false"
    :isControls="true"
    class="customClassName"
  />

  <VideoPlayer
    type="preview"
    previewImageLink="poster.webp"
    link="videoLink.m3u8"
    class="customClassName"
  />
```

If you need more details, visit this documentation
[vue-hls-video-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-hls-video-player?activeTab=readme)

Also, you can research hls.js, it is a base module for the vue-hls-video-player.

Also, I gonna add, this component maintains only .m3u8. For working with default formats, you need to use default video html tag